# how to run a .exe file in xul application?

Tags: xul

i want make a app with xul but some functions and logic in a stable exe file.
run the exe with xulapp that to do something  and get the result given to  the xul application,
how should i do ,thanks

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you want to do. Can you try to clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke another application using nsIProcess, but you can't easily obtain a result, except for the exit value. Attempts are being made to get a proper IPC component that will allow you to write to the process stdin and read from its stdout and stderr but this is not yet available in releases of XULRunner.