# How to launch an application using firefox plugin/extension?

Tags: firefox, xul

I am developing a firefox extension using XUL.I am able to create a button. Onclick of the button, I need to launch an application(eg:notepad). How can this be done?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nsIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/NsIProcess) is your friend for this.

See these references:

[how to run a .exe file in xul application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469490/how-to-run-a-exe-file-in-xul-application)

http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=511

Keep in mind that a plugin may be installed on a non-windows platform..

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I will try nsIProcess